# Rushing a paper to be published vs. taking the time and having a preprint by the time of PhD applications

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions

I'm a second semester MSCS student who's looking to apply to PhD programs in the US and Canada this coming applications round.

My field is machine learning, and with graduate applications already being very competitive, I understand that my field is in some kind of hype bubble right now and it's particularly competitive. I hear stories about applicants who have perfect scores and stellar research experience getting rejected from schools.

Although I personally think it's a bit unreasonable to expect master's students to have a first-authored paper by the time of application, it is what it is. And this is what led me to wonder.

I'm working on a research project right now, and my original plan was to submit the paper to a conference on June 1st. That's only about a month away, and my project's still a bit far away from completion. It's a little unrealistic to have a high-quality paper ready by then considering this isn't the only thing I'm working on (other research projects, lab responsibilities, classes, etc.) and so should I just focus on taking more time to raise the quality of my research and having at most a preprint by the time I apply, or is it still worth it to have an official conference publication?

Obviously, this is all under the assumption that my submission even gets accepted. My personal values and principles regarding research itself tell me to do the former (i.e. take my time), but I guess I feel like I'm in a time frame where it seems that having one more line on my CV would help.

There's probably not a right or wrong answer, but I was hoping someone with more experience and insight compared to me would be able to provide some tips or thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think you can get useful advice from someone who has not read your paper.

Comment: Hm. I think you should discuss this with your supervisor (or other real-life people). Besides that one cannot really answer like A. Physicist says, advice on the Internet is often biased in the direction of "don't rush and it's better for science if this is a high-quality paper and this would be more ethical". I am not saying this is right or wrong, just that this forum (and probably all other forums, especially those where people write under their own name) is probably biased.